# mysql read part of select statement from a file in a bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, import

I have a MySQL query I need to run multiple times in a bash script.
It has a very long list of regular expressions.
I would like to avoid repeating the long list multiple times in the script.
Code:

```
select * from tableName where fieldName regexp concat(
... big long list of regular expressions ...
);
```

The next MySQL command will have a different select criteria.
And other MySQL commands will have deletes instead of selects.
But the list of regular expressions remains the same.
I tried using the bash source command but MySQL interpreted that so I think this has to be a MySQL command.
So ... how can I do this ...

```
select * from tableName where fieldName regexp concat(
[import regular expression list from file]
);
```

Thanks in advance.
Update - bash attempt:

script1:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -uusername -ppassword -D dbname -e "select * from tablename where fieldname regexp concat(
source /scripts/script2
);"
```

script2:

```
'cat|',
'dog|',
'fish'
```

error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'source' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: It's not really clear where your problem is.  Show us your Bash attempt and the error message you are getting.

Comment: updated - refer above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate the snippets you need, then pass the lot to SQL.

```
#!/bin/bash
sed '1s/^/select * from tablename where fieldname regexp concat(/
   $s/$/);/' /scripts/script2 |
mysql -uusername -ppassword -D dbname
```

(To see what the `sed` script does, comment out the pipeline to MySQL.)

... or somewhat equivalently

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -uusername -ppassword -D dbname <<____HERE
  select * from tablename where fieldname regexp concat($(cat /scripts/script2));
____HERE
```

but you will run the risk of odd side effects if your [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) contains any shell metacharacters (like the asterisk here). In the worst case, maybe split it into a quoted part and an unquoted part.

... Or, disarm it with a slightly silly workaround:

```
#!/bin/bash
splat='*'
mysql -uusername -ppassword -D dbname <<____HERE
  select $splat from tablename where fieldname regexp concat($(cat /scripts/script2));
____HERE
```

Comment: Thanks.  I am trying to understand your advanced methods. On the second example ... what function does the <<___HERE and ____HERE have?

Comment: nevermind ... figured it out ... did not have to escape the asterisk after all

Comment: Thanks!  If you have the time to correct my errors, I am attempting to understand the first suggestion:  
'1s = do a substitution on line 1  
/^/ = match entire line  
select * from tablename where fieldname regexp concat(/ = replace with this line  
$s/ = insert data from input file here  
$/ = end of match  
); = end of mysql statement  
/' = end of substitution  
/scripts/scripts2 = input file  
| = pipe  
mysql -uusername -ppassword -D dbname = pass everything above to this

Comment: `^` matches beginning of line, so we insert the SQL snippet before the text on the first line of the file, and similarly after the end of the last line of the file (the first `$` addresses the final line and `s/$/foo/` substitutes in `foo` at the end of the line).

Comment: You do need to escape the asterisk, the fact that it did not explode in your face today offers no guarantee for tomorrow.

Comment: but when I escape the asterisk ... I get this error ... ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\*'.